# Clojure reducers library - folding with max

Tags: dictionary, clojure, reduce, reducers

I'm trying to convert the following example to the new Clojure 1.5 reducers library:

```
(reduce max (map inc (range 10))) 
;=> 10
```

When I change it- I get the following error:

```
(r/fold max  (r/map inc (range 10)))
;ArityException Wrong number of args (0) passed to: core$max  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:437)
```

Can someone give me a correct solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Notice that it works when you substitute `max` with `+`.

```
(r/fold + (r/map inc (range 10)))
; => 55
```

The difference is the fact that [unlike `+`](http://www.clodoc.org/doc/clojure.core/%2B) `max` [does not have](http://www.clodoc.org/doc/clojure.core/max) a case for an invocation with no arguments. `r/fold` requires the combining function—i.e. `max`—to provide an identity value when called without arguments. For `*` it's `1`, for `+` it's `0`.

A potential solution would be to define a `max'` which acts as `max` but when called with no arguments it returns the negative infinity—[an identity element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element) for the `max` function.

```
(defn max'
  ([] Double/NEGATIVE_INFINITY)
  ([& args] (apply max args)))
(r/fold max'  (r/map inc (range 10)))
; => 10
```

The same result can be achieved using the [`r/monoid`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/3e89a16b/src/clj/clojure/core/reducers.clj#L315) function.

```
(r/fold (r/monoid max #(Double/NEGATIVE_INFINITY)) (r/map inc (range 10)))
```

For further discussion see [*Reducers - A Library and Model for Collection Processing*](http://clojure.com/blog/2012/05/08/reducers-a-library-and-model-for-collection-processing.html), section *Simplicity is Opportunity*.

Comment: Ok - it looks like they discussed it in the Google group here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/clojure/reduce$20max/clojure/EJ9hOZ8yaos/TULab4pndwoJ

Comment: @Jan There's a helper fn called `monoid` for this, using that, your second code example reduces to e.g. `(r/fold (r/monoid max #(Double/NEGATIVE_INFINITY))  (r/map inc (range 10)))`

Comment: @EugeneBeresovksy, thanks, I didn't know about the `monoid` function. I've updated the answer.